# Is it possible to check if a user is in a building or not?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-indoor-maps

Is it possible to check the users exact location?
I mean is it possoble to check if a user is inside/indoor a building or not?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.wired.com/2014/12/google-maps-ground-truth/) but it's a No.

Answer (score 0):

There is thing called FusedLocationApi. With this you can determine what is the accuracy of your position and what is your actual location, but you can not check weather a user is inside a building or not. There is no possibility to check this at the moment.

Comment: After some hours of searching i found out that there is a google map for  buildings, that shows the map of the building. How the google map indoor that the user is inside the building to show the map?

Comment: I found this article - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639061/how-does-google-indoor-navigation-work

Comment: Yeah, you are right, that the google maps is also shows the maps of the buildings but the technology is not ready yet for give your the actual position in the buildings. In this question you found more about your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639061/how-does-google-indoor-navigation-work

Comment: OK....thank you very much for the answer.. I have one more question...is it possible to check if the road that user moves is a highway or a road only for shopping??